# GET custom url query from array of checkbox to string

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Hey i have a question how do i customise the query in the url when the form submit?

I have 3 search checkbox:

1. type
2. size
3. location

and when the user click apply it should change the url to:

> localhost:3000/?type=a,b,c&size=small,medium&location=central

instead:

> localhost:3000/?type=a&type=b&type=c&size=small&size=medium&location=central

Comment: Please post the HTML you're using to generate the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think your checkboxes looks like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="whatever">
```

When you change it to this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="whatever">
```

You'll be able to post multiple values in `type` variable. And `type` will become an array.